# Reproducible? Cannot Add Custom Metadata Record to Change Set if it References Id Field?

Tags: change-set, custom-metadata, gack

I have a `Custom Metadata Type` which contains a field mapping. There are four basic fields which seem relevant to this situation (though you could likely boil it down to just two):

- **`Source Object`** (Lookup to `EntityDefinition`)

  - **`Source Field`** (Lookup to `FieldDefinition`)
- **`Target Object`** (Lookup to `EntityDefinition`)

  - **`Target Field`** (Lookup to `FieldDefinition`)

Obviously, `Source Field` is dependent on `Source Object` and `Target Field` is likewise dependent on `Target Object`. I was able to add dozens of records to my `Change Set`, but two records in particular gack every time I try to add them. Both have a `Source Field` of `Record ID` (on different objects).

> **An internal server error has occurred**
>
> ...
>
> Error ID: 1131404664-21929 (-1515640453)

Is anybody able to reproduce this behavior? Should I pursue it as a bug? My instance is cs19.

Comment: I looked up the error id in internal salesforce tools, and I think there's something wrong with the field values in the records where field value is Id. Can you try setting it to another field, saving, setting it back to Id, and then try again to add to the changeset? If that doesn't work let me know. I'd also be interested in seeing what the raw field values of those fields are if you export the records with metadata api.